# Why are there two “vous” in “Comment vous vous appelez”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-réfléchis

Why are there two *vous* in “Comment *vous vous* appelez”?

I thought “vous” means "you" (formally). So why two *vous* instead of one, like the same idea of using one “tu” in “Comment tu t'appelles ?”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For pronominal or reflexive verbs in French (e.g. s'appeler, se laver, se demander, etc.), you start with the pronoun and follow with the *reflexive* pronoun, whether directly or inversely.

Reflexive pronouns are:

> Je **me**
>
> Tu **te** (**not** tu)
>
> Il/Elle/On **se**
>
> Nous **nous**
>
> Vous **vous**
>
> Ils/Elles **se**

The pronoun *vous* will always be used in conjunction with the reflexive pronoun (which also happens to be *vous*) in the case of reflexive verbs.

What may confuse you is the fact that the reflexive pronouns for *Je*, *Tu*, *Il/Elle/On*, and *Ils/Elles* drop the end vowel when followed by a verb that begins with a vowel.

So it will always be,

> « Vous **vous** demandez / Tu **te** demandes peut-être pourquoi l'on utilise encore vous... »
>
> « Je lui ai dit que vous **vous** appelez / tu **t**'appelles Marius, mais... »
>
> « Ma mère ne comprendra jamais combien il **s**'attache / vous **vous** attachez à ... »

Answer (score 4):

In "Comment tu t'appelles ?" there is also two "tu". The "t'" is also a "tu".

"s'appeller" is a pronominal verb. So we need to put a pronoun.

"Comment vous vous appelez ?" or "Comment vous appelez-vous ?" is like "How do you call yourself ?" in english. And as you can see, in this question, you can find two "you".

Comment: In "Comment tu t'appelles", the "t" is a "te" not a "tu".

Comment: "How do you call you" is not proper English. Better use "What do you call yourself?" And one expects a nickname rather than an actual name in response. So it is different than "What is your name?"

Comment: "What is your name ?" is the english for "Quel est ton nom ?".
Here I did not want to give the translate of "Comment vous vous appelez ?" because I think Shady Atef knows it. I wanted to give a sentence that is similar to give him an idea of "why is there two 'vous'" in that question. I know thats not syntaxically correct in english, but may be this can an idea of the semantics of "Comment vous vous appelez ?"...